# USB permission denied for non-root (e.g. lsusb) with latest Rasperry Pi OS

Tags: usb, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye

We have one Raspberry Pi OS with build `e2bab29767e51c683a312df20014e3277275b8a6` (bullseye 11, from 2021-10-30, kernel 5.10.63), in which `lsusb -t` works normally and shows all devices.

With the **newest** Raspberry Pi OS however, `lsusb` only shows the hubs, and `lsusb -t` shows tons of "/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-1.2.4.1:1.0/bInterfaceClass: Permission denied" errors. Also, despite `udev` rules, which used to work before, we can't access USB devices without root privilege. This build is `c6d56567ff6ef17fd85159770f22abcf2c5953ed`, bullseye 11, kernel 5.10.92.

Is there anything we missed that needs extra configuration with the updated kernel or with the distro update? Searches for USB permissions entirely point to `udev` permissions, but per-device permissions are really not our issue here.

Does anybody have an idea? This is Raspberry Pi 4 by the way, 32 bit distro.

https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspios_lite_armhf/release_notes.txt